# android os upgrade on custom device

Tags: android, upgrade

I am not sure this is the right platform to post this query.

My requirement :
I have a custom device on which ICS android is ported.
There is a need for software upgrade support for the future releases.
This is something which I have never tried or rather  say have no knowledge.

How is it done in standard devices ? say any commercial phone available in the market?

Answer (score 0):

if "software update" means firmware, I believe you have to handle it yourself on custom hardware. Perhaps (as I never checked myself) you could use existing code for firmware updater (assuming it's part of AOSP) as starting point.

Comment: Out of luck not available in AOSP